# How to separate plots better?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=5)

data.Interest1.value_counts().plot(kind = 'bar', ax=axes[0,0], color = "rosybrown")

massT5.Interest1.value_counts().plot(kind ='bar', ax=axes[0,1], color = "firebrick")
scT5.Interest1.value_counts().plot(kind ='bar', ax=axes[0,2], color = "red")
virgT5.Interest1.value_counts().plot(kind ='bar', ax=axes[0,3],color = "darksalmon")
nyT5.Interest1.value_counts().plot(kind ='bar' , ax=axes[0,4],color = "sienna")
```

I'm trying to plot 5 different plots and I'm not sure how to get rid of the bottom rows, when I change

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=5)
```

to

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=5)
```

I get an error saying IndexError: too many indices for array. Thanks in advance

[image: diagramm]

Comment: Use `fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=5, figsize=(12, 6))` at the beginning and `plt.tight_layout()` at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably because when you use `nrows=1`, the axis dimension will also become 1.

So, for example, instead of `axes[0, 2]`, you might try to use simply `axes[2]`.